# Recieving topic message in the same device from diferent projects

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

Im developing an ios application that uses Firebase Cloud Messaging for push notifications.
I have two different Firebase projects that I use for two different environments (UAT and PROD), one project for each environment. So each iOS app has its own Google-info.plist file.
I also have one device for each environment.

Here's what happened:

By mistake I installed the UAT app (with the UAT Google-info.plist file) on my PROD device.
And when I loggin and the device token is refreshed, the app automatically subscribe to a default topic (ie. /topics/default), so when I opened the UAT app in the PROD device the app subscribed to the default topic using the UAT firabase configurations.

At this moment I have uninstalled the UAT app and installed the PROD app into the PROD device, **BUT** when I send a message to the default topic (/topic/default) throught the UAT firebase project using its server key, the "PROD" device still receives the notification.

Is this a normal behavior?